# Symfony 2.8 Global variable

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony 2.8 and I didn't find anything to solve my problem.

To make it simple, I have a Payment entity and I need to have a global variable for the VAT.

My question is: is there any way to have a common variable to all my Payment entities knowing it could be modified later within the web application by the administrator? I don't think the Service parameters (which I am using) will make it. At least, I didn't find anything on how to modify it dynamically.

Here's some part of my service.yml:

```
parameters:
    app_tva: 20
```

Comment: Is there such thing as a config file in Symfony you can use to set this value at a config level?

Comment: When I manage TVA, tva's values are store in database. Then  i dev a twig extension to recover my value and calculate a price. I dont know if this what you want. Of course i can modify values in my dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use real global variable (`global $parameter`) in Symfony - the vary bad idea, because all systems works in scope (request, console, etc...), and each scope have custom services for this scope (`@request` as example).

But, if you want use config parameter in you application, then you can use:

**Solution #1 (Use `app/config/parameters.yml`):**

> This solutions vary good, if parameter is not dynamically, and changed rarely.

1. Add custom parameter in `parameters.yml`
2. Get this parameter from container `$container ->getParameter('some_parameter')`

**Solution #2 (Use a factory service for custom parameters)**

> In my application, I use custom layer for configurations with common
>   service, because many parameters is dynamically, and can changed for
>   each request or user or another condition.

1. Create a factory service `Acme\DemoBundle\Config\AppConfig` as example.
2. Add method `getVat` to this service.
3. Register service in service container.
4. Inject this service to another service, where you must access to configuration layer.

***Solution #3 (Use a Doctrine events)***

> So, this a not good idea, but can work in any systems.
>
> If you want calculate prices, or another operation with entity, you can inject custom parameter after complete load entity.
>
> **Attention:** This method work only after load entity via doctrine!

1. Create a custom listener/subscriber for [Doctrine ORM](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)
2. Inject custom variable to you entity in `postLoad` event.
3. Register listener/subscriber as service and add tag `doctrine.event_subscriber` or `doctrine.event_listener`

**P.S.**

I would use Solution #2, because this is a vary good variant, and we can store this parameter anywhere (database, redis, parameters.yml, etc..), and we can change this parameter for each condition (request, user, country, timezone, etc...)